# Create Database on Amazon Redshift with Query Editor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've created a Redshift cluster using the AWS management console. The cool thing that AWS setup was this query editor to be able to write queries directly on your cluster without having to install a SQL client on your computer.

However, I was trying to create a new database on the instance but it doesn't seem to be possible using AWS query editor. Am I right or did I miss something?

Comment: What did you try to run? What were the results? Were there errors? Your question needs to include more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indeed missed something, you simply need to go into your query editor and write

`CREATE DATABASE db_name OWNER=db_owner;`

Comment: For anyone else that got here... the default database name to auth to is "dev", it's hidden in the extra settings when creating the cluster.